# Scroll Down Menu

Tags: menu, web

Lets say I have a scroll down menu with ten options. That menu comes down when a user hovers over a link. Problem is...When the menu comes down, it covers a bit of the text beneath it on the page...Would it be better to have some of that text covered? Or should I have the link redirect to a different page with the options displayed there?

Comment: What's it blocking? I've found these drop downs very annoying when they cover form controls I need, but if they cover stuff like the Footer that's not relevant it's not as big a deal.

Comment: Can you screenshot it or include a mockup?

Comment: Do you need to see the text that's being blocked when you're using the menu?  I think the answer is no in most cases.  If you can provide a sketch, it would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always find these Scroll Down Menus very annoying :(
Some of the users has a personal habit of pointing with the mouse cursor while they are reading an article (I'm one of them), the big problem of these Scroll Down Menus is that they pop-up all off a sudden covering the article from you if you hover over them, even if the user don't want to click on the link. That is why I don't like them at all.

Your second option is better, to have the link re-direct to a different page with available options when clicked, or to show up the Scroll Down Menu only if the user clicked on the link. Because you can not assume that the user always want to click on the link.

Comment: *Why* is the second option better? Everyone has their own opinion on all topics but this site isn't going to be useful for people visiting if it's just full of lots of individual users opinions without any reasoning behind them. Can you provide a comprehensive answer and reasoning to back up your opinion?

Comment: @Jon W, I added more justifications, thank for pointing that out :)

Comment: Very true, indeed...